# What is the initialising value for top in stacks

Tags: java, data-structures

While I am practicing stacks I got a doubt  v          about initialising the top. 
Can someone suggest what is the good practice, either to take top = 0 or top = -1.

I am a newbie to Java, learning it now. 
Hope someone explains me about this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `0` is a good start value. Since you want the initial value to be the first one. Why would you start at `-1`?

Comment: I think either one works.  If you start at top = 0 then top is always equal to the number of elements on your stack.

Comment: I do not get why the to is downvoted. Is it that his english isn't meeting a top-notch so-quality? Or that he seems to not completely grasp the concept of a Stack? I think both are solvable, as his english is already quite good, and a stack is easy once it clicks. @K.Sindhu: Look up this [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/stack.html#java-stack-basics). What jenkov means with "top" is the highest position of the stack. As soon as you add one element to the stack it becomes the top position. You can't initialize a stack with a top variable in java. Have fun!

Comment: Re. downvote: my guess is there's no code, the question is opinion based, and the OP could have probably done some research on their own. @user3469861

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon which implementation of stack you are using(Array, LinkedList). Use can use either top=-1 or top=0 to represent empty stack, no as such hard rule. If you are using an Array based stack(e.g A[n]) then better to use top=-1 as array indexes starts from 0 to n-1 for an array of size n in java.
For 1st push operation, top=-1+1=0, refer to element A[0]

Comment: Use the editors functions to mark code as code and text as text. This makes your post more readable ;)